# I want to send the function data into the border designed using a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
    <title>Table-3</title>
</head>    
<body>
    <div style="border:2px solid red;width:250px;height:250px"></div><br><br>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var num = 2;
            for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                document.write(num + " * " + i + " = " + num * i);
                document.write('<br>');
            }
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here!</button>
</body>    
</html>
```

I want to send the function data into the `div`with the `border`styling using a button in javascript.. I have been trying from so much of time but i'm unable to crack it..Please Help Me!

Comment: "the border designed"? Huh? You mean the `<div>` that has some border styling?

Comment: what do you want exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) contains a working example. If you want to fill a element with content you need to get the element with javascript. I have given your div an id to insert your string.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id= 'border' style="border:2px solid red;width:250px;height:250px"></div><br><br>


</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var num = 2;
var str = "";
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    str +=(num + " * " + i + " = " + num * i);
    str +=('<br>');
}
document.getElementById("border").innerHTML = str;
```

Hope this helps.